# C Programming - Generating Random Numbers into a new text File and retrieving them to count the occurrences (then do statistics on the side)

Tags: arrays, c, printf

My goal is to generate random numbers into a new txt file where I can retrieve the randomly generated values and count the occurrences of the values (e.g. Number 1 has appeared "x" number of times). My expected output should display an output like the example given and all the occurrences should add up to 600. There is an underline on the last bracket in my newfile() function. Thanks in advance.

First 10 lines of txt output file...

2

5

4

2

6

2

5

1

4

2

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>

int newfile(FILE *fp)
{
  char fname[20];
  printf("\nEnter the name of the file...  ");
  scanf("%19s",fname);//File name cannot have spaces
  strcat(fname, ".txt");
  fp=fopen(fname, "w");
  int i, N = 600, newfile[N];
  for(i=0;i<N;i++)
  {
     newfile[i]= ((rand() % 6)+1);
     fprintf(fp,"%d\n",newfile[i]);
  }
}

int main() 
{
  int i = 0;
  FILE *fp;
  do
  {
    newfile(fp);
    i++;
  }
  while (i<1);
    FILE* fpointer;
    char filename[20];
    int value = 0, result = 0, num[600] = { 0 };
    float sum, mean;

    printf("\nEnter the name of the file...  ");
    scanf("%19s",filename);
    fpointer = fopen(filename, "r");

    if (fpointer == NULL) {
        printf("ERROR: CANNOT OPEN FILE!\n");
        return -1;
    }

    result = fscanf(fpointer, "%d", &value);
    while (result == 1)
    {
        {
            num[value] = num[value] + 1;  // num[value]++
        }
        result = fscanf(fpointer, "%d", &value);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i <= 6; i++) {
        if (num[i] > 0) {
            printf("Number %i has appeared %d times\n", i, num[i]);
        }
    }
    
    sum = (1*(num[1])+2*(num[2])+3*(num[3])+4*(num[4])+5*(num[5])+6*(num[6]));

    mean = sum / 600;
    printf("\nThe mean is %f",mean);


    fclose(fpointer);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There is no question here!!!

Comment: @goodvibration Sorry about that. I just wanted to know why my code isnt running as intended.

Comment: @Tee in which way " isnt running as intended" ?

Comment: @4386427 I get the output "mean = 0.0000" when I'm supposed to get an output "Number 1 has appeared "x" number of times" and "mean = 3.412" etc.

Comment: @Tee Did you open the txt-file in an editor to see if the file looked ok?

Comment: @4386427 Yep my txt file came out as intended.

Comment: @Tee Did you try to print out the values inside the loop that reads the text file? Like `printf("%d\n", value);`

Comment: @4386427 Yep my text file had output 600 values from line 1 - 600 but my program didn't read and record the values properly.

Comment: @Tee Did you try to count how many values you read from the file? Do that and use it here: `mean = sum / 600` --> `mean = sum / COUNT`

Comment: @Tee Post the first 10 lines of the txt file (use the "edit" link and add it to the question)

Comment: @4386427 I'll try this then :D

Comment: please add the actual erro you are getting to the question

Comment: regarding: `char fname[20];
  ....
  scanf("%19s",fname);
  strcat(fname, ".txt");`  if you enter a file name of 15 or more characters, then the call to `strcat()` will overflow the `fname[]` buffer, resulting in undefined behavior

Comment: OT: regarding: `fp=fopen(fname, "w");`  always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  If not successful (==NULL) then call `perror( "fopen failed" );` followed by: `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`

Comment: OT:  regarding: `while (result == 1)
    {
        {
            num[value] = num[value] + 1;  // num[value]++
        }
        result = fscanf(fpointer, "%d", &value);
    }`  Why the extra braces '{' and '}' ?

Comment: why have the same file open in `main()` and opened in `newfile()?

Comment: regarding: `int newfile(FILE *fp)` and `int i, N = 600, newfile[N];`  the use of the same name for the function and for a variable within that function is a very poor programming practice and (especially with older compilers) result in a recursive call.

Comment: OT: the posted code contains some 'magic' numbers.  'magic' numbers are numbers with no basis.  'magic' numbers make the code much more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  Those 'magic' numbers are: 6, 20, 600.  Suggest using `#define` statements or a `enum` statement to give those 'magic' numbers meaningful names.  Then using those meaningful names throughout the code

Comment: regarding: `int newfile(FILE *fp)` and `fp=fopen(fname, "w");`  This will modify the pointer on the parameter list, but not modify the `file*` back in the `main()` function.

Comment: OT: regarding; `do
  {
    newfile(fp);
    i++;
  }
  while (i<1);`  why the loop?  all that is needed is: `newfile( fp );`

Comment: OT: regarding: `printf("ERROR: CANNOT OPEN FILE!\n");`  Error messages should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout`.  If the failing function is a C library function, Then should also output the text reason the system thinks the error occurred.  The statement: `perror( "fopen failed" );` handles all of that.

Comment: regarding: `sum = (1*(num[1])+2*(num[2])+3*(num[3])+4*(num[4])+5*(num[5])+6*(num[6]));`  1) only 6 elements of the array `num[]` are being used, so the size of the array can be reduced to 6.  2) in C, array indexes range from 0 ... (number of elements in array -1)

Comment: regarding: in main(): `scanf("%19s",filename);
    fpointer = fopen(filename, "r");`  and in newfile(): `scanf("%15s",fname); strcat(fname, ".txt");  fp=fopen(fname, "w");`  this means the user has to enter two (somewhat) different file names, one with the extension and one without the extension.  This will be very confusing to the user.

Comment: OT: rather than obtaining the file name twice, suggest obtaining once near the beginning of `main()` and passing the resulting char array to `newfile()`.   Remember to call `fclose()` in `newfile()` so the 'new' file is fully ready to be re-opened and read in the `main()` function

Comment: OT: suggest: rather than opening/closing/opening/closing the file, Only open it once early in `main()` with mode "w+" and before returning from `newfile()` to call `rewind();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem in your code is that you forgot to close the file inside `newfile` function.

So just add `fclose(fp);` at the end of the function.

Minor issues:

you don't need to pass `fp` to the function `newfile`. Just use a local variable.

`newfile[N]` is not needed at all. Simply do: `fprintf(fp,"%d\n", (rand() % 6)+1);`

`num[600] = { 0 };` is much too large as you only use index 0 .. 6

Before doing `num[value] = ...` you should check that `value` is in the expected range, i.e. to avoid writing out of bounds.